# Proof of reputation on a subject

Tags: protocol-analysis

I'm mulling over the need for a proof of reputation performed on a subject.
When a guy starts to build a future he has to start here from scratch, his previous reputation does not matter, but it is not true, there is a lot of value in his contributions on GitHub, opinions on the previous Twitter or followers on LinkedIn... If that guy wants to win reputation and is able to authenticate on the aforementioned platforms, could an AI score its reputation based on evidence… is this such a bad idea?
I didn't find anything out there, am I searching wrong?
I'm a fan of this, I don't work in this community and this is all a bit big for me, so I don't know what the line of work is, but isn't defining this protocol and implementing it valuable?

Comment: You mean tracking the user's full history of activities?